# Import problem with Flutter fluent_ui package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run a simple fluent_ui code but I'm getting this error:

```
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-1.2.3/lib/src/controls/form/text_box.dart(42,35): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'details' of the method '_TextBoxSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp' has type 'TapUpDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragUpDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp'. [C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop\Projects\diary\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-1.2.3/lib/src/controls/form/text_box.dart(58,42): error G4906CC7E: The parameter 'details' of the method '_TextBoxSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDragSelectionEnd' has type 'DragEndDetails', which does not match the corresponding type, 'TapDragEndDetails', in the overridden method, 'TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onDragSelectionEnd'. [C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop\Projects\diary\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluent_ui-1.2.3/lib/src/controls/form/text_box.dart(52,25): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'TapUpDetails' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TapDragUpDetails'. [C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop\Projects\diary\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(249,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop\Projects\diary\build\windows\CMakeFiles\7d71bf6297f51133f7fd6107266f56fa\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop\Projects\diary\build\windows\CMakeFiles\85b20ae6c1bd697a2d9652d3be36f5b1\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop\Projects\diary\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

The code I'm trying to run:

```
import 'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return FluentApp(
      theme: FluentThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          accentColor: Colors.blue,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 24)),
      darkTheme: FluentThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
          accentColor: Colors.blue,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 24)),
      home: NavigationView(
        appBar: NavigationAppBar(title: Text("Fluent Design App Bar")),
        pane: NavigationPane(
          displayMode: PaneDisplayMode.auto,
          items: [
            PaneItem(
                icon: Icon(FluentIcons.home),
                body: SizedBox.shrink(),
                title: Text('Home')),
            PaneItem(
                icon: Icon(FluentIcons.insert),
                body: SizedBox.shrink(),
                title: Text("Insert")),
            PaneItem(
              icon: Icon(FluentIcons.view),
              body: SizedBox.shrink(),
              title: Text("View"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_quill: ^7.4.6
  fluent_ui: ^1.2.3
  flutter_acrylic: ^1.1.3
  system_theme: ^2.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**This same code worked fine on my computer job with a fresh install of flutter / visual studio, etc.** I don't understand why this code can't run on my own machine. Both vscode and Android Studio recognize the *'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart'*, but the parameters theme, darkTheme, NavigationView and everything below is not recognized.

I have downloaded the git repository of fluent_ui and their example project runs absolutely fine!

What I have tried:

- delete the flutter folder and download it again
- flutter upgrade --force
- flutter pub cache delete
- flutter pub cache repair

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is caused by a bug in the `fluent_ui-1.2.3` package. This bug has been fixed in the latest version of the package.

To fix the problem, you can try the following:

1. Update your Flutter dependencies to the latest versions.

https://pub.dev/packages/fluent_ui

2. Run the following commands in your terminal:

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`

This will clear the Flutter cache and force the app to download the latest dependencies.

Comment: It looks like I had dependency constraints somewhere. It says "fluent_ui 1.2.3 (4.7.4 available)" and after I did flutter pub upgrade it showed "No dependencies changed.
8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints." I had to do flutter upgrade --major-versions to solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @NeoFahrenheit Happy to hear that :)